# Looking into a checkpoint file

Tags: python, tensorflow

What is the easiest way of looking into a checkpoint file (saved by `tf.train.Saver.save`)? i.e. the stored `tensor`s, their shape, name and values.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer here. it's a tool for reading checkpoints.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py

Comment: See also the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051466/tensorflow-checkpoints-simple-load . inspect_checkpoint uses that class internally.